# Kubuntu 14.04 as guest in VirtualBox on Win 7 host

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, video, vlc

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 guest in VirtualBox with Win 7 host. I have video issues. Videos frequently appear on top of everything else, even things they shouldn't - like menus. If I drag a player on the screen, the video stays where it is until I release the player, then the video snaps into the frame again.

I've found that in VLC by changing the video output setting to "X11 Video output (XCB)" I can make the problem go away, but that's only in VLC. I'd like to fix it system-wide, but I can't find any settings. Since I'm in a Virtualbox, I don't believe I have any options on the video card beyond the provided InnoTek VirtualBox Graphics Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Disable 3D and set the video output to "X11 Video output (XCB)"

If I didn't enable 3D acceleration, video playback freezed in vnc when I chose full screen playback. So I enabled 3D which solved the full screen problem, but gave me the problem you describe.